# MySQL update table 1 with table 2 data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, synchronization, sql-update

Sorry for the ambiguous title.

I have two tables:

table 1: `mailing_email`

table 2 (dynamic table but for now is): `membership`

table 1 contains a list of all email accounts in the database and few ancillary fields such as name. It also has a column called `communicate`.

`communicate` is basically my terminology for `subscribed`. Any unsubscribe link will set `communicate` to false.

Both `mailing_email` and `membership` have a `email` and `communicate` column.

I need to write a query where the following happens:

`mailing_email.communicate` gets updated to the current status of `membership.communicate` where `mailing_email.email` = `membership.email`. If an email exists in `mailing_email` which does not exist in `membership`, the `communicate` field stays the same.

How would i go about doing this the fastest possible way? Each table will have thousands of rows this sync command would run often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL offers an `update join` syntax:

```
UPDATE mailing_email
JOIN   membership ON mailing_email.email = membership.email
SET    mailing_email.communicate = membership.communicate
```

Comment: That works perfectly :) and it only took 0.18 seconds over 4k rows on each table. just what i was looking for, thanks :)